# Pandas broadcast with numpy scalars

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Pandas objects (for example a `DataFrame`) can broadcast operations with python scalars. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])*2
```

But when performing the same operation with a [numpy scalar array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])*np.array(2)
```

pandas returns an error:

```
ValueError: Incompatible argument shape: ()
```

In Pandas documentation I can't find any mention that Pandas does not support numpy scalar-arrays broadcasting.

Is this a bug or a known limitation? Workarounds?

*I'm using pandas 0.14.1 and python 2.7 from anaconda.*

Comment: For what it's worth, `pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3])*np.array([2])` works.  I don't know why the scalar array doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. I found this because loading a scalar from  a txt file with `np.loadtxt` returns a scalar array. I could wrap the value with `np.atleast_1d` but it looks awkward for no clear reason.

Comment: If the array is coming from `loadtxt`, then a work-around might be to use `ndmin=1` in the call to `loadtxt`.

Comment: I guess this should work. pls open an issue on github. a pull request to fix would be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a pandas bug that is solved in current master and in the upcoming 0.15 version.

The issues was reported [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8116) and fixed [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8119).